# Generalized commutator

Tags: lie-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, derivations

A well-known generalization of the commutator for operators is the so-called q-commutator defined as
$$[A,B]_q=AB-qBA.$$
I was wondering if the case where $q$ is not a number but other operator has been studied or is interesting for some reason, i.e.
$$[A,B]_Q=AB-QBA.$$
with $Q$ an operator. Things of this kind can arise when studying Cuntz algebras but I haven't found anything.